# Rename machine by IP (not hostname) in powershell

Tags: powershell, rename, hostname

I'm dealing with a situation where there are 2 machines with the same hostname and different IPs. One of them needs to be renamed. I found that machine can be renamed remotely using the next command:

```
Rename-Computer -ComputerName "Srv01" -NewName "Server001" -LocalCredential Srv01\Admin01 -DomainCredential Domain01\Admin01 -Force -PassThru
```

But this one is accepting hostname not IP.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's only two devices... just RDP into it and update it manually.  You didn't post enough information to be helped.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 , the issue is that I need to do this automatically. The machine to be renamed is a clone and it's name needs to be updated

Comment: Run `Rename-Computer` locally on the remote machine via `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers `Invoke-Command` won't work over IP address.

Comment: Try adding temp hostname for the clone system by editing `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.

Comment: @AOY I don't understand what you mean "automatically".  You're still entering a command at a shell and doing it manually.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, I create a Jenkins Job which contains powershell scripts that are run on the cloned machines in scope of activity where machine needs to be automatically cloned and configured before handing it to the end user.

Comment: Wuh, why!?  Why aren't you properly building images?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes, it does. You need to add the IP as a trusted host first, though: `Set-Item WSMan:localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value $ip -Force`. And you need to provide explicit credentials, but the OP is doing that anyway.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers that's a lot more work than "just use icm", though.  By default, without NTLM, it doesn't work.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, I have to use existing API for cloning machines (which works perfectly fine with non domain machines but is not capable of renaming domain machines - I can't use another tools for this task).

Comment: @AOY Wrong tools for the job

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Running one additional command is not "a lot more work" where I come from. YMMV.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers There's just a lot of assumptions that come with `Invoke-Command` in the first place (proper configuration, supported OS determines whether it's on by default, etc. This isn't a server OS, OP states it's a user desktop being cloned)

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers, I'm sorry. I have almost no experience with powershell.
Could you please provide example how the command will look like when using Invoke-Command

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'd agree that the OP is likely using the wrong tool for the intended purpose, but your statement *"`Invoke-Command` won't work over IP address"* is just flat-out wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer?view=powershell-6#parameters):

> **-ComputerName**
>
> Renames the specified remote computer. The default is the local computer.
>
> Type the NetBIOS name, ***an IP address***, or a fully qualified domain name of a remote > computer. To specify the local computer, type the computer name, a dot (.), or localhost.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Thank you!